# What is the time of a datetime field in a database if only the date is entered?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, datetime, adp

I am working on an Access adp that has its data stored in sql-server. I have a sql statement that inserts the date part of a dateTime object into a datetime field of a table.

```
INSERT INTO...DateValue(myDateTimeVariable)
```

What is the time defaulted to?
(I am hoping that it defaults to 12:00 AM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defaults to 12:00 AM.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it defaults to 12:00 AM.

As you could have seen with a simple test.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from [table where you inserted to] 
where key = [key you used to inserted to]
```

Comment: Can you explain what issue in the original question your pseudo-SQL is designed to address?

Comment: To quote Andomar "As you could have seen with a simple test."

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get how your pseudo-SQL reveals that. And it's not technically an answer to the question.

Comment: I'd rather not downvote a useful answer. At this point I can't see it as useful, so I wouldn't downvote it just because I don't get it. I only downvote when I know the answer is wrong or misleading. If I don't know for sure, I'll leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. 12:00 AM